# Whats the point of initializing properties inside another empty variable init()?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, structure

Im confused on whats the goal in setting the `width` and `height` properties equal to `widthInit` and `heightInit`?

They're only being put into another variable with no value...???

How is this being so called "initialized"?? and whats the difference between this and the declaration of (width/height) in the beginning of the structure? They were declared with no value and and now they are being put into variables with no value also???? please help!

```
init(widthInit: Double, heightInit: Double) { 
  self.width = widthInit 
  self.height = heightInit
}
```

Comment: I think you have to read about Object Oriented Programming(OOP) and understand the purpose of constructors(init in Swift), and in Swift you don't need to make a default constructor for `struct`'s.

Comment: you should read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203

Comment: @VictorSigler The thing is I have already read about OOP concepts and have been studying about them for weeks, I don't see anything about constructors in the book, but I believe they are just another word for initializers, or the init() method. Would be great if you helped me in answering the question.

Comment: i just gave you the link

Comment: @Lamar thanks, I just read through it. So basically initializers are kind of like "instance methods" that are called when you create an instance and send in a value as an argument to the init method...?

Comment: @Ali There a lot of good articles about the `init()` process in Swift out there, you need to search it only. With `init in swift explained` in Google you give a lot of results. I hope this help you.

Comment: I was not the one asking for it lol @VictorSigler

Comment: Sorry my mistake @Lamar.